# C Output for Homework

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    signed int bit=512, mBit;
    {
        mBit = ~bit;
        bit = bit & ~bit ;
        printf("%d %d", bit, mBit);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

a. 0, 0
  b. 0, 513
  c. 512, 0
  d. 0, -513

Guys I am not having the answer of this question and also not able to interpret the question.so could you please provide your answers with proper explanation.

Comment: There's not even a question there!

Comment: I think he wants to know what the output will be from his four multiple-choice options. Why not just try it?

Comment: The question asks you what the program will print. There is your interpretation. Now you can attempt solving it!

Comment: The question, as stated, is not entirely clear. It looks like part of a multiple-choice question.

Comment: Guys You are all maestoes and you must understand that it is a multiple choice question and you have to select one option and that is what i have posted in my question.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a compiler? Paste the code in there, run it, and find out what it runs. Man, this would be cheating if it wasn't a programming class!

Comment: Even worse, the question (not this, the underl;ying multiple-choice one) is badly formulated, in that it requires a 2-complement representation (not guaranteed by the C standard) to havethe (presumed) correct answer.

Comment: It just took me about 15 seconds to paste the code into http://codepad.org and run it: http://codepad.org/jYheOfFF - don't students *try* anything for themselves these days ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is d: http://ideone.com/frKOz

- bit is 0 because `bit & ~bit` always results in a zero (`1000000000 & 0111111111`).
- mbit is -513 because inverting 512 is -513.

**Edit: Why is `mbit` -513?**

See explanation of signed-integer-handling: http://www.rwc.uc.edu/koehler/comath/13.html

Comment: +1 for using a compiler.

Comment: mbit is -513 because inverting 512 is -513.Could you pls elaborate your saying

Comment: That's what a boolean / binary not of 512 becomes in [two's complement (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.

Comment: @Rup: ITYM *one's complement*